# Как найти дерево папок\файлов из внутренней папки

Tags: java, файлы

Делаю код для постройки дерево из папок и файлов. Изначально мой код получает что-то, и если там пусто `if (!file.exists())` возвращает пустой `String`, если есть файл возвращает название файла.

```
public Optional<String> tree(Path path) {

        File file = new File(String.valueOf(path));
        if (!file.exists()) {
            return Optional.empty();
        } else if (file.isFile()) {
            return Optional.of(file.getName());
        } else if (file.isDirectory()) {
            ...

        }
        return null;
    }
```

Трудности начинаются когда есть папка. В этом случае я должен посмотреть всё что в ней есть и в случае если есть папка посмотреть что в ней и так далее. Пытался сделать при помощи `if-else` конструкции, но эта конструкция работает только до того уровня который задан в `if-else`, а надо чтоб не было рамок, и программа выдавала результат всей цыпочки.

```
else if (file.isDirectory()) {
            System.out.println(file.getName());

            File[] filesArray = file.listFiles();
            for (File filer : filesArray) {

                if (filer.isFile()) {

                    System.out.println(filer.getName());
                } else if (filer.isDirectory()) {

                    System.out.println(filer.getName());
                    File[] filesArrays = filer.listFiles();
                    for (File filers : filesArrays) {
                        if (filers.isFile()) {
                            System.out.println(filers.getName());
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    System.out.println(filer.getName());
                }
```

При такой конструкции получил результат, но а если в папе inner1 есть например папка inner 1.1 с файлами, тот же самый результат будет:

```
test1 
inner1 
some.txt 
some1.txt 
some.txt 
some1.txt 
some2.txt
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте использовать рекурсию для данной задачи:

```
    void printRecursiveTree(Path path) {
        File file = new File(String.valueOf(path));
        if (file.isFile()) {
            System.out.println(file.getName());
        } else if (file.isDirectory()) {
            File[] filesArray = file.listFiles();
            for (File filer : filesArray) {
                printRecursiveTree(filer.toPath());
            }
        }
    }
```

Небольшой бонус - вы можете сделать дерево файлов более реалистичным, применив отступы:

```
    void printRecursiveTree(Path path, int level) {
        File file = new File(String.valueOf(path));
        if (file.isFile()) {
            System.out.println(" ".repeat(level) + file.getName());
        } else if (file.isDirectory()) {
            File[] filesArray = file.listFiles();
            for (File nestedFile : filesArray) {
                printRecursiveTree(nestedFile.toPath(), level + 1);
            }
        }
    }
```

Вызов функции:

```
        printRecursiveTree(Path.of("C:/Users/oQaris/Desktop/Git"), 0);
```